# Oracle SQL - Last 12 full months of data

Tags: oracle, date

I need a query that will dynamically pull the last 12 full months of shipping data (excluding current month). So with today being September 30, 2016, I would need data from September 1, 2015 to August 31, 2016. Tomorrow, the query would change to the date range of 10-1-15 to 9-30-16.

Here is what I have currently:

```
WHERE (shipdate BETWEEN TRUNC(sysdate, 'Year') AND sysdate)
```

This query pulls data from the beginning of the calendar year up to TODAY's date instead of the previous 12 completed months. I have found answers for this with MySQL and MS SQL Server but not for Oracle. How can this be accomplished in Oracle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
between add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'month'), -12) and trunc(sysdate, 'month')
```

If a shipment may actually be timestamped at exactly midnight and shipments with a timestamp of Sept. 1 at 00:00:00 should not be included, then "between" should be changed to

```
shipdate >= add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'month'), - 12) 
                               and shipdate < trunc(sysdate, 'month')
```

Comment: this includes the data from   "01.09.2016  00:00:00", which is not desired

Comment: It depends on the actual business; I assume no one ships at midnight, but if that is a problem you are correct. I just edited the post to reflect that.

Comment: Mathguy, this worked perfectly. Thanks so much! Fortunately, we're never shipping anything at midnight, so I just used the original query.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a table with a list of dates, for example last 1000 days:

```
create table tableTest(shipDate) as
(
    select trunc(sysdate) - level +1
    from dual
    connect by level < 1000
)
```

you can use the following:

```
select min(shipdate), max(shipdate)
from tableTest
where shipDate between trunc(add_months(sysdate, -12), 'MONTH') and TRUNC(sysdate, 'MONTH') -1
```

Comment: This will miss shipments after 00:00:00 on August 31; if you really want to use "between" and adjust the endpoint, perhaps subtract 1/86400 (one second) from `trunc(sysdate, 'month')`

Comment: what if you have data up until 2019 and you want to get data from last day of 2019 to last day of previous year without hardcoding the dates in WHERE statement. Can't use Max grouping function as its not allowed in WHERE statement... any idea?